# Buddypress registration submit to which file?

Tags: registration, buddypress

I mean what file the register.php submit to?

```
form action="" name="signup_form" id="signup_form" class="standard-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data
```

notice the form action=”"… where is the file?

I need to edit the the file that insert the registration data to db.

This is important someone please tell me thanks!

Comment: Anyone can tell me how is the registration process? I just couldn’t find the action or function for registration process...

Comment: there are lots of people asking this question but I havent seen any conclusions

Answer (score 0):

It should be the page you set in the buddypress settings.
The default is /register.

Answer (score 0):

Check the bp-members folder, inside you will find the file "bp-members-screens.php". The data goes that way before registering the users. Might not solve your question entirely but it sure will help because THERE is the answer to your title.

Why? I was asked to create a WP site with BuddyPress but their security is terrible, I was having lots of ghost registration and spammers. When I tried to check for the submit action I found out it's empty so it was harder to add extra security... well I did it placing extra routines in THAT file, so there goes the action submit.

I took my time to research and there is no clear info on the web, this is the closest I could get and finally solve my problem.

Good luck.